# Angular use html template from a component inside another component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two components. The first component is a table component --> selector: 'table-component'. This component implements a standard filtering on my table.

My second component is a component for a page that displays the table.
I have multiple pages that use this table component by using the  tag.

But some pages need some custom filtering. So how can I add custom filtering in the table component like this?

```
<table-component>
     <custom-filtering>
          <div>
               Here has to come the filtering stuff
          </div>
     </custom-filtering>
</table-component>
```

Comment: use `ng-content` , have you tried ?

Comment: I suppose you should use [ng-content](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b). Your `table-component` seems to be a kind of container component, with `ng-content` you can personalize its contents.

Comment: That's what I was looking for indeed

Answer (score 0):

In your customFiltering directive you must add this

```
return {
    transclude: true,
    /* your code */
    ...
    ...
}
```

and then you need to add this to your template

```
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
```

This mean when you write custom html between tags

```
<custom-filtering>
    // html code here
</custom-filtering>
```

html code between tags will replaced where your

```
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
```

in your template..

Is that what you are looking for? Hope this help you

Other way to archive what you want is to extend your customFiltering directive and pass custom filter